# Xcode cannot find iTunes Connect profile?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I've set up an iTunes connect profile like so:

[image: iTunes connect profile info]

And I created an archive in xcode which has the following information:

[image: archive info]

But when I try to validate the archive I get the following message:

[image: error]

I have no idea what's wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Sure You set the status to `Ready To Upload` in iTunes Connect, The button is located in the top-right corner of the App Detail page

**UPDATE**: The Button Looks Like This: [image]

Comment: Didn't realize I actually had to press the button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually click the button saying you're ready to upload a binary for the app in iTunes Connect.